# How to invoke ACS Call from Power Portal

Tags: powerapps, azure-communication-services

Is there a way in which ACS calls can be invoked with a Power Portal. How can we install npm packages within Power portal

Answer (score 0):

The Power Platform is a low-code/no-code platform and does not allow you to install custom components.
it is possible by extending the functionality by creating and hosting a service , and then exposing that to the power platform by defining a [Custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/register-custom-api).
In your own service which hosts the functionality , you are free to add any component from the NPM ecosystem that you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install npm packages there are few ways to achieve this.

**Option 1:**

1. Check if the npm has CDN
2. Then in Portal management > In any of the web pages > advanced section of custom javascript > add the script tag and include the CDN

**Option 2:**

1. Download the npm packages to your local.
   2.In Portal management > web files > upload the npm file and reference it in any of your web page or entity form.

Comment: the OP is asking about the PowerApps, Your answer in no way takes that isto consideration and seems to be a boilerplate answer that adds no value.

Comment: Hi @Jos. The question is about powerapps portal. Not powerapps. Adding custom libraries is allowed in Powerapps portal as a web file.